# Filtered SUM in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very new to Oracle. I am writing a SQL statement against an Oracle 10g database. My table has a date field, DATA_DT, with multiple entries for each date. I want to get SUM of the number field, BQWP, for each of these dates. To get the sum of BQWP for a specific date, my select statement would be:

```
SELECT SUM(BQWP)
FROM tasks 
WHERE TRUNC(DATA_DT) = TO_DATE('07/19/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Now, how can I loop through all dates and get the SUM for each in a single SQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to aggregate the entries by date:

```
SELECT TRUNC(DATA_DT),SUM(BQWP)
FROM tasks 
GROUP BY TRUNC(DATA_DT)
```

Look at this document for further information:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions003.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT TRUNC(DATA_DT) as data_dt, SUM(BQWP) as sumBqwp
FROM tasks 
GROUP BY TRUNC(DATA_DT)
```